# Sending emojis to backend and getting them back

Tags: ios, unicode, utf-8, emoji

I need to send a NSString that could contain emojis to my backend and then get it back.
The guy working on the Android version of this app is sending the emojis with the format '\\ud83d\\udcfb', so I'm encoding my text using this:

```
NSString *uniText = [NSString stringWithCString:[textToEncode cStringUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The problem is that when I'm getting it back from the backend, I get something like 'ud83dudcfb' and then I can't transform it back to an emoji.

The Android guy says that I need to send 4 "\", like "\\\\ud83d\\\\udcf"', but I don't know how to do it.

I don't think that creating a loop to add two backslashes before each code is a good solution.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert emoji to unicode -

```
NSData *data = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *Value = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

To convert unicode to emoji -

```
NSData *data = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *Value = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have the same problem: data is sent correctly to the server, but when I get it back, it looks like this: @"Some emojis... u2764ufe0fud83dude48", so the unicode to emoji converter has nothing to convert.

Comment: You need to check if the string saved on server matches to what you have sent. In this string u2764ufe0fud83dude48 how can you add "\" user can type this as a plain string as well.

Comment: That is the problem. I don't know why but the server just strips the backslashes. I had to add a couple more of them before sending the string to the server, but I did use your code to encode y decode the text, so I'm going to accept your answer. Thank you.